# Get total rows count those are affected, WHEN update with SQLExecDirect

Tags: visual-c++, odbc

If I use `SQLExecDirect` to execute the query:

```
UPDATE mytable set mycol = 2 where mycol = 1;
```

How can I know how many rows have been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/sqlrowcount/)

Function Prototype:

```
SQLRETURN SQLRowCount(
  SQLHSTMT hstmt,           /* 32-bit input -- statement handle */
  SQLINTEGER *RowCount      /* 32-bit output */
  );
```

Sample Example:-

```
#include "sqlcli.h"
SQLINTEGER row_count;
...
if (SQLExecDirect(hstmt,"UPDATE QUERY HERE;",SQL_NTS)>=0) {
  if (SQLRowCount(hstmt,&row_count)>=0) {
    /* The value of row_count is 1. */ } }
```

Comment: Thank you Piyush, I tested it and it work perfectly.